# How can i pass []string as ...interface{} argument

Tags: go, slice, variadic

I know how to pass it when the arguments are `... strings`

But this case is a bit different:

```golang
func main() {
    args := []string{"hello", "world"}
    fmt.Println(args...)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/7ELdQQvdPvR

The above code throws the error `cannot use args (type [] string) as type [] interface {} in argument to fmt.Println`

What would be the most idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that I need call `Println` once with all the arguments.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón, the information was very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in one of two ways:

```
   args := []interface{}{"hello", "world"}
   fmt.Println(args...)
```

Or:

```
  args:=[]string{"hello", "world"}
  iargs:=make([]interface{},0)
  for _,x:=range args {
     iargs=append(iargs, x)
  }
  fmt.Println(iargs...)
```

You can pass a `string` where an `interface{}` is required, but you can't pass a `[]string` where a `[]interface{}` required. The compiler converts `string` value to an `interface{}` value, but that is not done for arrays, and you have to do the translation yourself.